# Worst-case minimization of size of intersection of an offset set with a given set

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

Consider the set of first $N$ natural numbers i.e., $S_N$ = $\{1,2,3, \dots,N\}$. Let $S^k$ be a finite subset of $S_N$, where $|S^k|$ = $k$. We define another set $O$ whose elements $\in$ $\{0,1,2,\dots, (N-1)\}$ and $|O|$= $m-1$.

We now define the following process: **for each $i$ $\in$ $S_N$, construct the derived $m$-element set $$S_i^O = \{i, i+O_1, i+O_2,\dots, i+O_{(m-1)}\}$$. Please note that we take modulo $N$ to ensure that no element of $S_i$$^O$ exceeds $N$.**

We're interested in knowing (a) what properties of $S^k$ is $C^O$ = $\max_{i}(|S^k\cap S_i^O|)$ a function of (for a given set $O$)?, and (b) if there's an (preferably efficient) algorithm for determining an optimal set $O$ (say, $\widehat O$) that minimizes $C^O$, and (c) what $C^{\widehat O}$ is.

**My progress so far**

Let's define a distance matrix $D^{S^k}$ as: $D^{S^k}_{i,j} = (s^k_j - s^k_i+N)\pmod N$. Note that $D^{S^k}_{i,i} = 0$ and $D^{S^k}_{i,j}+D^{S^k}_{j,i} = N$. For $j\neq i$, we define $d^{S^k}_{i,j} = min(D^{S^k}_{i,j}, D^{S^k}_{j,i})$ and note that $d^{S^k}_{i,j}$ can take at most $\binom{k}{2}$ unique values.

Special case of $\lceil \frac{mk}{N}\rceil$ = 1.

Here the problem of finding $\widehat O$ amounts to avoiding the elements of $d^{S^k}_{i,j}$ $\forall i,j$. Note that an assignment of this kind is always possible provided $N - \binom{k}{2} \geq m$. Thus $C^{\widehat O} = 1(=\lceil \frac{mk}{N}\rceil)$ for $k\leq min(\lfloor\frac{N}{m}\rfloor, \lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{1+(8(N-m))}}{2}\rfloor)$

For $\lceil \frac{mk}{N}\rceil >1$, my conjecture is that $C^{\widehat O} = 1+\lceil \frac{mk}{N}\rceil$. Additionally, I think this can be achieved by the following algorithm for constructing $\widehat O$ (verified by hand for small non-trivial cases: e.g., for $N=11, m=5, S^k=\{3,5,6,9\}, \widehat O = \{1,2,3,4\}$ achieves $C^{\widehat O} = 3$):

**1) Sort unique $d^{S^k}_{i,j}$s in ascending order of their frequency. 2) Get rid of elements from this list whose frequency is lower than ($\lceil \frac{mk}{N}\rceil -1$). 3) Choose the first $m$ elements in the remaining list.**

However, I'm looking for ideas to either prove or disprove this conjecture (and, hence or otherwise arrive at the algorithm).

**Background**

I'm an electrical engineer with elementary background in combinatorics, number theory and graph theory. The problem is an abstraction of a real-world situation of system-design under constraints with guarantees on worst-case performance.

Comment: What are you getting if you apply your algorithm to the case $N=36$, $k=9$, $S^k=\{4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36\}$ and $m=6$, say? The point is that in this case all $d_{ij}$ are multiples of $4$, so it looks like (correct me if I'm wrong) your algorithm gives $\widehat O$ consisting of multiples of $4$ as well, which is, clearly, the *worst* choice you can make, not the best one. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @fedja, you're right. I hadn't considered such regular cases since they're unlikely to happen in the real-world application I have in mind. Nonetheless, it does point to a clear shortcoming that needs to be addressed. Broadly speaking, considering $D^{S^k}$ alone is likely insufficient. We'll likely need to incorporate elements of the off-diagonal block of the bigger matrix $D^{S_N}$ (i.e., pair-wise distances between $S^k$ and $S_N \setminus S^k$). The more I think about it, it looks like this should be mappable to a graph partitioning problem but the details have been elusive so far.

Comment: Just curious, what are the actual magnitudes of $N,k,m$ you are thinking of? I have a couple of ideas but I want to make a reality check on them myself before posting anything.

Comment: @fedja, typical numbers are in the range of: $N$~150 to 300, $m$~10 to 100, $k$~5 to 25% of $N$

Comment: OK, give me a few days then. BTW, it seems to me that you've made one logical error in the sentence "Here the problem of finding amounts to $\widehat O$ avoiding the elements of $d^{S^k}_{i,j}$". What it really amounts to in my opinion is finding $\widehat O$ such that *its difference set* avoids those elements, which is much harder.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @fedja, not sure if I agree with that. Considering the special case of $\lceil\frac{mk}{N}\rceil$=1, every potential collision can be shown to be equivalent to a case where $i \in S^k$ for some $i$ (since every edge in a graph is incident on two nodes). So $O$ avoiding elements of $d^{S^k}$ should suffice.

Comment: Let's run an example: $S^k=\{5,6,7\}$, $N$ is large (so the "over the cycle" differences are big) and $O=\{4,6\}$. Then $O$ avoids the set of $d_{ij}$ (which is $\{1,2\}$), but take $i=1$ now. What am I missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112810/discussion-between-kartik-and-fedja).

Comment: Hi! Just curious if you are still out there :-) If yes, check the chat.